# PHP / JavaScript to dynamically change image paths

Tags: php, javascript, joomla, path, hyperlink

This is my first question, hence please ignore mistakes, if any.

I have an issue where I am serving three alternate layouts to my visitors based on the device they are surfing from.

**Mobile, Tablet,** and **Desktop**.

My website is in PHP and I am using just 280 bytes of JavaScript to determine the browser width of my visitor. There is no other JavaScript or any libraries like jQuery, MooTools. I want to keep my site very very light weight thus resulting in faster page load speeds.

I have a PHP variable called `$layout` and the the value to it is assigned by the JavaScript dynamically based on the browser width. The three values assigned to it are `mobile or tablet or desktop`

Now I have links in my xhtml which are like this:

```
<img src="cdn/images/desktop/image1.jpg" width="500" height="200" alt="image1">
<img src="cdn/images/desktop/image2.jpg" width="500" height="200" alt="image2">
<img src="cdn/images/desktop/image3.jpg" width="500" height="200" alt="image3">
```

By default images are loading from the `cdn/images/desktop` folder.

What I am looking for is if the value is `$layout` is `tablet` then the images should load from `cdn/images/tablet` folder and similarly if the valur of `$layout` is `mobile` then images should load from  `cdn/images/mobile` folder.

Name of the images remain the same. They are three different resolutions in three different folders.

Kindly suggest a PHP solution if possible to do this in PHP.

Otherwise please suggest a **plain JavaScript** solution *(No libraries like jQuery, MooTools ot any such)*

Thanks

**UPDATE**

Actually I am using Joomla as a CMS so in my posts I cannot use PHP code within posts hence I want that after the page is rendered or during the rendering these paths must change.

Comment: Proxy the answer through another PHP script - works with joomla and everything else, just needs some webserver configuration.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$(function(){
        //mobile or tablet or desktop
        var client='<?php echo $layout; ?>'
        if(client=='desktop'){
            //do nothing
        }else if(client=='tablet'){
            $('#image-list img').each(function(){
                $('this').attr('src',$(this).attr('src').replace('desktop','tablet'));  
            });
        }else{
            //mobile
            $('#image-list img').each(function(){
                $('this').attr('src',$(this).attr('src').replace('desktop','mobile'));  
            });
        }
    });
```

---

```
        <div id="image-list">
        <img src="cdn/images/desktop/image1.jpg" width="500" height="200" alt="image1">
        <img src="cdn/images/desktop/image2.jpg" width="500" height="200" alt="image2">
        <img src="cdn/images/desktop/image3.jpg" width="500" height="200" alt="image3">
    </div>
```

---

use jQuery

---

sorry i didn't know it don't require lib.

```
    var client='<?php echo $layout; ?>'
    var list=document.getElementById('image-list');
    var img=list.getElementsByTagName('img');
    for(var i=0;i<img.length;i++){
        //img[i].src=img[i].src.replace('desktop',client);
        img[i].setAttribute('src',img[i].getAttribute('src-data').replace('desktop',client));
    }
```

---

put it in the end of file.

---

```
<img src-data="cdn/images/desktop/image1.jpg" width="500" height="200" alt="image1">
```

---

Comment: Hey thanks for the help but loading an entire jQuery library just to achieve this is not a good idea specially when I am trying to maintain a very very light weight site.

Comment: Hey it works but the challenge here is that first it is loading the `normal` image and then again replacing it with tha `small` image. This way it is loading 2 images in place of one.

Comment: I have posted new code, setting  a new img's attribute with 'src-data' and changing javascript with new code. : )

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<img src="cdn/images/<?php echo $layout; ?>image3.jpg" width="500" height="200" alt="image3">
```

Comment: Actually I am using Joomla as a CMS so in my posts I cannot use PHP code. I what I want is after the page is rendered or during the rendering these paths must change.

Comment: Your answer is also missing the trailing / character.  While not required, it makes the html well formed XML.  `<img src="cdn/images/<?php echo $layout; ?>/image3.jpg" width="500" height="200" alt="image3"/>`

Answer (score -3):

why don't you use simple javascript to change the src of the image ?
it's maybe not the most nicely looked script but you can do something like this:

xhtml file :

```
<img id="image1" src="cdn/images/desktop/image1.jpg" width="500" height="200" alt="image1">
<img id="image2" src="cdn/images/desktop/image2.jpg" width="500" height="200" alt="image2">
<img id="image3" src="cdn/images/desktop/image3.jpg" width="500" height="200" alt="image3">
```

after the javascript find out which layout is it just do:

```
document.getElementById("image1").src = "cdn/images/" + layout + "/image1.jpg";
document.getElementById("image2").src = "cdn/images/" + layout + "/image2.jpg";
document.getElementById("image3").src = "cdn/images/" + layout + "/image3.jpg";
```

is that what you mean ?

Comment: Actually these links are being generated by the CMS and on every page they will be different. Can I not use a simple JavaScript function which will look for a path like `cdn/images/desktop/` and replace it with `"cdn/images/" + layout + "/"`, If yes what will be the correct code for it? Please help.